# Python Selenium Webdriver: Cannot locate confirmation dialog (reveal-overlay class object) after submit button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, aws-lambda

I'm using Selenium Webdriver and python to automatically schedule an appointment.

Webdriver options:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

I was able to select the date I want for the appointment and to find the submit button.

The html of the submit button (you can see the dialog configured at the data-confirm attribute):

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Reprogramar" id="appointments_submit" data-confirm="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;¿Desea reprogramar esta cita?&quot;,&quot;ok&quot;:&quot;Confirmar&quot;,&quot;cancel&quot;:&quot;Cancelar&quot;}" data-disable-with="Por favor, espere." class="button primary">
```

How I'm finding it:

```
appointments_submit = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'appointments_submit')
appointments_submit.click()
```

However, when I click the submit button, it creates a confirmation dialog (which doesn't appear in the body of the page until this moment). Not matter how much I try, I cannot made the web driver able to locate this element.

Html of the element:

```
<div class="reveal-overlay" style="display: block;"><div data-reveal="ib04bi-reveal" class="reveal " role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; top: 97px;">
  <h2 data-confirm-title="" class="h3 text-center alert-icon">¿Desea reprogramar esta cita?</h2>
  <p data-confirm-body="" class=""></p>
  <div data-confirm-footer="" class="text-center">
    <a data-confirm-cancel="" class="button secondary">Cancelar</a>
  <a class="button alert">Confirmar</a></div>
<a aria-label="Close modal" class="close-button" data-close="">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-times"></span>
  </a>
  </div></div>
```

Picture of it:
[element webdriver cannot locate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCPiq.png)

This is where is failing:

```
confirmation_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > div.reveal-overlay > div > div > a.button.alert')

confirmation_button .click()
```

```
[ERROR] NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{
    "method": "css selector",
    "selector": "body > div.reveal-overlay > div > div > a.button.alert"
}
```

I also tried WebDriverWait but is not working neither as is throwing a TimeOutException:

This didn't work neither.

```
confirmation_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.reveal-overlay > div > div > a.button.alert")))
confirmation_button .click()
```

Please help me troubleshoot this issue. I'm feeling really stuck with it.

PD: I'm running the code in a python3.7 aws lambda function

PD2: This dialog element that webdrive cannot locate is part of the `<body>` of the webpage. The thing is, **it only appears after clicking the submit button**. I'm sharing some screenshots of the before and after.

[Before clicking the submit button (only 6 div are showing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwksF.png)

[After clicking the submit button (a 7th div appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKa3p.png)

This 7th div is the element webdriver cannot locate.

Comment: Are you sure the first `<div>` in the posted html is a direct child of the `<body>` element?

Comment: Right-click the element in the browser, inspect it, and look at its full xpath.  That might help you see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon . The <div> is part of the <body> I'm pretty sure. The thing is, it only appears after clicking the submit button. I added some screenshots of these at the botton of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy and embarrased to inform that I was able to resolve this issue one day after posting this question.

The issue was because I forgot to pick the earliest available day by clicking it. That's why clicking the submit button wasn't opening the dialog window (because it was disabled) and therefore, webdriver was not able to locate it.

```
earliest_available_date.click()
```

I made this mistake because I was testing the webscrapping locally opening the ui but when I'm deploying to the lambda function I'm using the --headless option.

Only in the lambda I forgot to add that line of code.